# I Have a problem with pgadmin I dont now how solve it

Tags: pgadmin-4

I was workin in pgadmin 4 when I accidentaly separarte a panel, I close the program and now just appear me the menu bar incomplete and the list of servers and it cant be used
[image: postgress desktop app blank]
I desinstalled pgadmin and install again but nothing changed

I expect that pgadmin become normal again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To properly restore the PgAdmin's interface you need to go to `File > Reset Layout`

[image]

Comment: But in my case dont appear me that option

Comment: Yeah, I now see you don't even have all the menu options... I know you said you've already tried to uninstall it but if it's the pgAdmin version installed with PostgreSQL (placed within C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL) then install a brand-new version (I've never managed to uninstall the pgAdmin installed with PostgreSQL). If it's a standalone installation placed in "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4" then this time uninstall it with CCleaner or Revo Uninstaller, make sure not to leave any files of the previous installation and then install the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete: `C:\Users\[yours]\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin`
you will lose all connections but don't have to `reinstall`.